# Problema com container's no docker

Tags: docker

Bom eu tinha configurado um container do postgress ontem funcionando normalmente, mas hoje eu fui entrar e utilizar o docker ps 
e não lista nenhum container, tentei criar novamente um container do docker utilizando:

```
> docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=spirit -e
> POSTGRES_PASSWORD=3613 -e POSTGRES_DB=testando -d -p 5432:5432
> postgres
```

mas deu esse error:

```
Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/postgres" is already in use by container "2825eac0fd684e17fe79c7e2ff92b214862e34425545eac6d3195f2fb5b6e66a". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

falando que já tem um container com esse nome, mas em docker ps não aparecer :(

eu tinha essa dúvida ao desligar o pc como eu inicio um container e alguém poderia me ajudar com esse error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu já tentou usar o comando `docker ps -a`? É o comando que lista todos os containers existentes na sua maquina.

Comment: @Wilian Freitas deu certo realmente kkk o -a salvou, não entendi pq negativaram sua resposta, obrigado man!!

Comment: Fico feliz que deu certo. Tu pode consultar outros comandos: [link](https://woliveiras.com.br/posts/comandos-mais-utilizados-no-docker/)

Answer (score 0):

Tive o mesmo problema, faz assim:
Executa o comando `docker restart /postgres` ou `docker rm /postgres` (para remover). Mesmo ele não estar listando no ps, ele ainda tem um serviço em execução. Tente lembrar o nome do container que voce subiu e mesmo sem aparecer no ps, execute o comando.

Tive esse problema no Ubuntu, hoje só dou um restart e funciona

Comment: o problema é que estava dando só docker ps era docker ps -a kk ai deu certo.. vlw man!!

Answer (score 0):

No seu caso o docker ps lista os containers que estão rodando atualmente, já a tag -a lista todos, inclusive os parados, no seu caso seu container parou por algum motivo. 
Você pode usar o docker start ( nome do container ) para subi-lo